# Failure when try register pjsua2 over NAT

Tags: c++, qt, nat, pjsua2

I am trying register the pjsua2 "(pjsip)" at a pabx sip, this register and work fine when not have nat, but when have nat it do not register. [I am using the standard settings used by demo](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/intro_pjsua2.html#using-in-c-application).

```
bool SipAccount::start(){
    this->ep.libCreate();
    // Initialize endpoint
    this->ep.libInit(this->ep_cfg );

    // Create SIP transport. Error handling sample is shown
    this->tcfg.port = this->port;
    try {
        this->ep.transportCreate(PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, this->tcfg);
    } catch (Error &err) {
        std::cout << err.info() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Start the library (worker threads etc)
    this->ep.libStart();
    std::cout << "*** PJSUA2 STARTED ***" << std::endl;

    // Configure an AccountConfig


    this->acfg.idUri = idUri.toLatin1().data();
    this->acfg.regConfig.registrarUri =  regUri.toLatin1().data();

    this->acfg.callConfig.timerMinSESec = 120;
    this->acfg.callConfig.timerSessExpiresSec = 1800;

    this->cred.username = this->username.toLatin1().data();
    this->cred.scheme = "digest";
    this->cred.realm = "*";
    this->cred.dataType = 0;
    this->cred.data = this->password.toLatin1().data();

    this->acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.push_back( this->cred );

    // Setup the account
    SipLine *l = new SipLine();
    l->setHandler(this->handler);
    l->create(acfg);

    // Here we don't have anything else to do..
    this->line = l;
    // pj_thread_sleep(10000);
    return true;
}
```

My problem is with the rport using the pjsip, i no set the credential, the port used to communication is invalid.

This is a sample from a header used in a test

[image]

Comment: With NAT (Network Address *Translation*) you don't really have a public IP the peer can connect back to (at least not without some extra work/complication). NAT is *not* how the internet is/was supposed to work - it's an ugly hack.

Comment: @JesperJuhl the my problem the use of library pjsip, has error from communication. Something is missing.